# Backbone not binding events to jQuery Popover

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

This question seems similar to those asked in a few other posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400626/jquery-binding-live-events) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624929/backbone-view-el-confusion/5757160#5757160).  I feel like I understand the concept, but I'm still having issues.

I am using the Twitter Bootstrap stuff for javascript popovers; the popover is where I want to bind events.  The Bootstrap javascript inserts/removes the html each time you call .popover('show')/.popover('hide').  The events that are bound to the html inside of the popover do not get called.  From what I read, Backbone uses jQuery.delegate() so it shouldn't matter if the html exists, but something is not working correctly

```
events:
    "click"             : "popover"
    "click .close"      : "close_popover"
```

Of these events, the first click event works but not the second (which is inside the popover).

```
popover: ->
  @el.popover('show')
  @delegateEvents(@events) #added from link

close_popover: ->
  @el.popover('hide')
```

Thanks.

Working on a jsFiddle that duplicates the problem.  Added the code from the suggested [link](http://backbonefu.com/2011/08/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-ui-modals/)--still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give us more of your View code?  A jsFiddle would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Can you confirm that an element with class `close` exists as a child of your view's `el`, and that it's what you're actually clicking on? (Try right-clicking on the element and inspecting it with Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug).

Comment: You are right. It's not part of the el. It works if I change the el reference. E.g. 

`popover: -> 
  @el.popover('show') 
  @el = $(".popover") 
  @delegateEvents(@events)`

but then I lose the binding to the element that calls the popover. In this [image](http://cl.ly/303b0Z0N3C2C0z3y2y24) you can see the popover and the calendar event. If I change the el, then after I close the popover, clicking on the element doesn't open it anymore. Would it make sense to reset the el back to the event element on close?

Comment: Yeah, you want `@el` to be fixed... instead, since you're binding to an event to an element outside of `@el`, you should do that binding from your `render` event. It should look something like: `$('.close').live 'click', -> ...`.

Comment: Thanks.  I am curious, what is wrong with changing `@el` in the view?

Comment: It's just confusing, that's all. There's nothing wrong with changing what `@el` points to, but there is something wrong when you as the programming don't know what it's pointing to at any given moment because it depends on some state somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing some indentations that are crucial when writing CoffeeScript:

Instead of

```
events:
"click"             : "popover" 
"click .close"      : "close_popover"
```

You want to indent the events

```
events:
    "click"        : "popover"
    "click .close" : "close_popover"
```

Without that indentation, the events become properties of the object, not of the "events" property and they will never be registered.

Comment: If this was not the cause, check out these resources: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869820/i-cant-get-backbone-js-events-to-trigger-when-the-view-is-within-a-fancybox/7874926#7874926

http://backbonefu.com/2011/08/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-ui-modals/

Comment: ah, the indentation is my fault on entering the code to the post.  In my code they are indented.  Thanks!