# backbone and twitter-bootstrap popover

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

This is a very similar question to [Backbone not binding events to jQuery Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983636/backbone-not-binding-events-to-jquery-popover) - however the answer does not seem to meet my needs.

I wish to bind a (twitter bootstrap) popover to one of my views, but not sure how I am supposed to do it?

```
events : {      
    "hover .info" : "showDetails",      
},
render : function(){        
    var content = this.template.tmpl(this.model.toJSON());
    $(this.el).html(content);       
    return this;
},
showDetails : function() {

    this.$(".info").popover({title: 'Hello', content: 'World'});    
    this.$(".info").popover('show');        
    console.log(this.model.get('description'));
},
```

My template looks like

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
  <div class="well listitem" style="padding: 14px 19px;">
    <div class="row show-grid" title="Irregular three column layout">
      <div class="span6">${heading}</div>
      <div class="span1">${price}</div>
      <div class="span1"><button class="btn info">Details</button></div>        
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

So I am trying to show some text in the popover when the mouse enters the button and vanish when mouse leaves - however on mouse over

1. The popover appears with undefined as the heading
2. On mouse out it stays in position.

I think I am not binding properly but would be great if someone could see my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Jquery `hover` event needs two callback functions, one for `mouseenter` and one `mouseleave`. In your case you pass only one function that will call on mouseenter and open your popover. From the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> Calling $(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut) is shorthand for:
>   `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

So change your code like this will fix your second problem:

```
events : {      
    "mouseenter .info" : "showDetails", 
    "mouseleave .info" : "hideDetails"     
},
render : function(){        
    var content = this.template.tmpl(this.model.toJSON());
    $(this.el).html(content);       
    return this;
},
showDetails : function() {

    this.$(".info").popover({title: 'Hello', content: 'World'});    
    this.$(".info").popover('show');        
    console.log(this.model.get('description'));
},
hideDetails : function() {
    this.$(".info").popover('hide');   
},
```

Comment: Thanks - worked a treat. FYI for anyone doing something similar, title and content should be functions not text e.g. popover({title : function() { return 'Hello'}});